# extract matrix from bs (b spline) function output in R

Tags: r, matrix, bspline

Let `x = c(1, 2, 3)` be a vector. I use `bs` function in the `splines` package of `R` to generate a matrix of B splines evaluated at `x`.

```
require(splines)
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
bs.x <- bs(x, knots = c(1.5, 2.5))
```

The output `bs.x` is as follows,

```
              1         2         3          4 5
[1,] 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0
[2,] 0.05555556 0.4444444 0.4444444 0.05555556 0
[3,] 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 1
attr(,"degree")
[1] 3
attr(,"knots")
[1] 1.5 2.5
attr(,"Boundary.knots")
[1] 1 3
attr(,"intercept")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"class")
[1] "bs"     "basis"  "matrix"
```

Clearly, besides the basis matrix, `bs.x` has other attributes. **My question is how to get rid of these attributes.** I need to do this, because  ultimately, I need to run `Matrix(bs.x)`, which throws me the following error message.

```
Error in as(x, "matrix") : 
internal problem in as(): “bs” is(object, "matrix") is 
TRUE, but the metadata asserts that the 'is' relation is FALSE
```

I guess this is because `matrix` is one of the classes that `bs.x` belongs to. At this moment, I do the following dumb thing.

```
bs.x <- matrix(as.numeric(bs.x), nr = nrow(bs.x))
```

Is there a better alternative? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could save the dims, remove all the attributes and then reassign the dims. That should be fairly efficient and avoid copies. Something like `dims <- dim(bs.x) ; attributes(bs.x) <- NULL ; dim(bs.x) <- dims`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a whole lot better, but

```
attributes(bs.x) <- attributes(bs.x)["dim"]
```

seems to work. (Reassigns the attributes of `bs.x` to be *only* the `dim` attribute.)